# Multiple UpdateSourceTriggers for one control

Tags: c#, wpf, updatesourcetrigger

Simple problem, let's say I have this TextBox (which, as a matter of fact, I do have):

```
<TextBox.Text>
    <Binding  Path="MySourceProperty"
              Mode="OneWayToSource"
              UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
</TextBox.Text>
```

It will succesfully update MySourceProperty whenever its Text property changes. What I want in addition to that is to MySourceProperty to get updated also when TextBox get focused.

**Is there a way to have two UpdateSourceTriggers for one control?**

---

For the details, I have a parent view containing a Label, bound to MySourceProperty, and another view, which contains a TextBox and a ComboBox.

So MySourceProperty should be updated when any of these events occur:

- TextBox.Text changes
- ComboBox.SelectedItem changes
- TextBox get focused
- ComboBox get focused

The last two events are obviously here because giving focus to a control doesn't change its Text or SelectedItem property, thus doesn't update MySourceProperty either.

---

EDIT: I've put the question in bold to be clear about what I want. I could solve the issue by using event handlers in code behind, but I'm trying hard to lose my WinForms habits. But if it is the only solution, feel free to answer with it.

Comment: What's the problem you are facing at the moment (while `MySourceProperty`  doesn't get updated when `TextBox` or `ComboBox` get focused)?

Comment: No, no, it does get updated. I want it to ALSO get updated when my TextBox get focused.

Comment: If it's not get changed why do you need it to be updated?

Comment: I explained it (I think) in the second part of the question. When my ComboBox's selected item changes, MySourceProperty get updated, cool; but now, when I focus my TextBox, its value is still ComboBox.SelectedItem until I changes its Text value, when I want it to become TextBox.Text automatically.

Comment: OK, looks like you are doing it wrong, why do you need a `textbox` and a `combobox`? You can just use one `ComboBox` with [`IsEditable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.iseditable(v=vs.110).aspx) set to true, then data bind `ComboBox.Text` and `ComboBox.SelectedItem` with your `MySourceProperty`. Isn't this more user-intuitive?

Comment: Well, the question isn't about my design choices.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this helps you Kilazur

I would give a try first as [Erno](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26342742/2466650) mentioned, if that won't fit your scenario then I have done something similar to this.

1. Set the UpdateSourceTrigger to Explicit.

> TextBox Name="itemNameTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=ItemName,
>   UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"

2. Then call the UpdateSource in respective events in code behind (which you mentioned above).

   ```
   // itemNameTextBox is an instance of a TextBox
   BindingExpression be = itemNameTextBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
   be.UpdateSource();
   ```

Referred from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: That was the first thing I thought about, indeed.

Comment: I agree Kilazur, though we feel like avoiding code behind habit, there are some design limitations leads us to depend on them :).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to put these controls that represent an entity in a single data template or user control. Then bind the datacontext of that control to the selected item of the combo box. The binding will now be relative to the selected item and will update automatically. No need to handle focus or multiple update triggers.

Comment: What about the TextBox? I'm new to WPF and have a hard time seeing how it would work.

Comment: As I said: Put all the controls that should change with the selection in a user control. Their bindings will be relative to the datacontext of the usercontrol

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to have two UpdateSourceTriggers for one control?`

The answer to your question is no. And even if it dose, the other Trigger is `LostFocus`.

If you are really like you said:

> I could solve the issue by using event handlers in code behind, but I'm trying hard to lose my WinForms habits.

Then based on my understanding: you are using two control `TextBox` and `ComboBox` to update a single property `MySourceProperty`. My suggestion is that you should use `TwoWay` binding, or you can actually combine them by using `ComboBox` with [`ComboBox.IsEditable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.iseditable(v=vs.110).aspx) set to true, and data bind `ComboBox.Text` and `ComboBox.SelectedItem` with your `MySourceProperty`.

***Edit***: If you do need to do it the way you are doing, then instead of using just one property, the better way of doing it is to bind `TextBox.Text` and `ComboBox.SelectedItem` to two different properties. Then your `MySourceProperty` should return either of them based on their focus status.

Comment: As I told you in comments, the question doesn't address my design choices. Believe it or not, I need to have these two controls.

Comment: @Kilazur, edited my answer. I'm not questioning you in any way, just give suggestions, and even if you don't like them, there will be others who may find this answer useful.